# MPI: master-slave with the master also doing work

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm implementing a standard MPI master/slave system: there is a master that distributes work, and there are slaves who ask for chunks and process data.

However... if implemented in a naive way (rank==0 is master, the rest are slaves), the master ends up doing no real work, but still takes one core for what needs practically no real computing power. So I tried to implement a separate "scheduler" thread in the master, but that involved sending MPI messages to itself, and didn't really work...

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Think about whether a scheduler thread is necessary.  I'm assuming you are running the application on a single machine.  If you use a separate thread in rank 0, you have 2 threads sharing a core.  If you just start one more rank in the job, you also have 2 threads sharing a core, but with much simpler code :)

Comment: Indeed, that would work nicely on one machine... even on more, if rank=0 regularly gets started on the box I'm starting it from (seems to be so this far).
Where I'd like to end up running it though is a cluster with a scheduler that will allocate a core for each thread, and I can't really influence that one.

Answer (score 3):

As I realized after some googling: you can send messages to yourself using **tags**. Tags are a kind of filter: if you do a *recv* for only tag==1, then you'll receive only those, with later messages being able to overtake eariler ones.

So, as for the solution:

- tag the "scheduler to worker" and "worker to scheduler" messages with a different id
- if rank==0: start a scheduler thread
- afterwards, regardless of the rank, request work.

This way, the rank 0 worker won't receive its own "let's give me work" messages, because they will have a "to be received by the scheduler only" tag.

**Edit**: this thing doesn't really seem to be *thread-safe* though... (= it sometimes crashes in "free()" even though it's written in Python...) so I'd be still interested in the real & proven solution :)

Comment: I'm guessing you are using mpi4py.  I looked at mpi4py initialization, and it should try to bring up MPI in a threadsafe manner by default.  What does `MPI.Query_thread()` return?  What's the underlying MPI library?

Comment: The MPI library should be initialised with a call to `MPI_INIT_THREAD` (`MPI.Init_thread()` in `mpi4py`) instead of calling `MPI_INIT`. Also the required thread level should be set to `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` and the returned supported level (or the return value of `MPI.Query_thread()` in `mpi4py`) should be checked - some MPI libraries should be compiled in a special way in order to support fully thread-safe calls and may fail to provide `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` otherwise.

Comment: Also note that if you are using Open MPI on a cluster with InfiniBand and request full thread support, then the native IB module is disabled (because it is not thread-safe) and only IP connections (possibly IPoIB) are used.

Comment: You're right, I've been running things so far with `MPI.Query_thread()` being 0. It seems though that switching threading support on is both tedious and inefficient (@HristoIliev  IB support being disabled is a thing I would have never realized, thanks for pointing that out!)  so I guess the solution I've described is still not the way to go. But then... what is?

Comment: You could spawn a worker thread to do the job and then probe for a (global?) `finished` flag peridically while waiting for an incoming message (`MPI_Iprobe` + `MPI_Test`), so that all communication is done outside the worker thread. It would make the master loop quite complicated but at least it should work. The other possible solution is to look for another MPI implementation, which provides full thread support and still function over IB (though you might not really need the low latency and the high bandwidth of native IB connections in the master/worker scenario).